# stream data into my vega view progressively

Tags: vega

I am using Papaparse to parse the CSV and on each data, I run an insert into the view, like so:

```
Papa.parse(createReadStream('geo.csv'), {
header: true,
chunk(data) {
    console.log('chunk: ', data.data.length)
    // data.data.length > 0 && tally.push(...data.data)
    view.insert('test1', data.data)
},
complete() {

    view.data('test1').length // this will return 0
    console.log('memory:', process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024, ` == time: ${Date.now() - start}`)
},
```

})

the only way to keep inserting new data is to either:

1. call run() after insert, `insert('test1', data.data).run()` to "commit", but I do not need it to run yet, not until I have all of the data (which is why I run() in the complete() callback).
2. I would have to parse everything at once in memory then pass it using `data('test1', allRows)` (which I think, will use a lot more memory)

how do I progressively stream data into my vega view? Note that I am running this inside a web worker, as far as I know, vega loader does not support browser's File instance (only URLs for browser environment) this I'm using papaparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `runAsync` and await it before inserting more data into the view or otherwise updates may bet lost. See https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2513 for more information on this.

If you don't care about intermediate updates while more data comes in, I would recommend collecting all the data you want to insert and then adding it at once. Memory won't be an issue since you will need all the data in memory anyway. Vega will keep the full data in memory anyway.